# GitHub Action to Review Status Checks

Tags: github-actions

Is there a way from a GitHub Action against a PR to review the status of checks against the PR?

I have a number of CI actions setup against my PRs and depending on which pass or fail, I want to act accordingly.

For example, if I have two actions ci-1 and ci-2 on my PR, I want to check if ci-1 or ci-2 passed or failed so I can then take remedial actions.

I tried checking the API but could not find anything relevant.